# Adding iOS 8 Splash Screen causes App to distort

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have Old App working correctly with following Config of Splash screens
[image]

and this is how it should look
[image]

But as soon as i turn on iOS 8.0 and later and add splash 
[image]

My App behave drastically weird like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Man, use LaunchImage for iOS 7 (mostly), for iOS 8 and above, add LaunchScreen.xib, or as alternative, you can say your Main.storyboard as launch screen option:

[image]

Comment: same issue after using Launch screen

Comment: Your app now launches correctly. You have hardcoded layouts for your screen, which is connected to 320 point screen width. Now you have go through your screens and make them use autolayout with proper constraints, or handle stuff in code, if that was intention before. As a prove of concept - I bet you have no such problems launching simulator for iPhones 4s/5/5s. Correct?

Comment: but why it worked as expected if i Don't add Launch screen OR iOS 8 splash

Comment: because then it was rendered 320 points wide, and scaling up, not using full device resolution.

Answer (score 0):

For **Device using iOS 7** you can do as usual, what we used to do using `images.xcassets`
[image: 1]]
For **Device using iOS 8** you can use **LaunchScreen.xib**

> Please note that if your application is developed on Xcode version <
>   5.0 then it is only compatible to 320px width devices (iPhone 4,4s,5,5s). You have to manually change constraints by checking devices/OS version.